# Don't get any result in EventStore Projection

Tags: projection, eventstoredb

Heeey all hopefully you can help me out with the following.

I have build a small hangman game, well at least I've build the backend. It's event sourced and I use eventstore as an event store. I've got some events in the store and I created a projection which unfortunately doesn't return any results.

What I want to achieve with this projection is very simple. It should show the word to guess per game that is going on right now. I'll listen to one event ("HangmanBackend.Domain.GameStarted").

```
fromCategory('hangman')
.foreachStream()
.when({
    $init: function(){
        return {
            game_status: "in progress",
            word_to_guess: ""
        };
    },
    "HangmanBackend.Domain.GameStarted": function(state, event) {
        state.word_to_guess = event.word;
        return state;
    }
});
```

All streams (1 stream per game) are prefixed with hangman, that why I can use "fromCategory" in the projection.

Is there any clear reason why I don't see any results?

Already many thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you see any events of that type in the admin UI? I mean the `EventType` property. It would help if you can post at least one event data and metadata or the UI screenshot.

Comment: to experiment change "...GameStarted" to $any... see if you get any events. You also probably also need to use event.data.word... but maybe log your event to make sure.